# Node.js with express - npm start do not work

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line, express

I have problem trying to run node app in Windows 7.I have installed express generator globally and with it help created a `test_app` directory and installed the modules. In the package.json  scripts look like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  }
```

However, when i run `npm start` it just returns this in console:

```
test_app@0.0.1 start C:\work\test_app
node ./bin/www
```

If i try to run node app.js nothing happens. Before there wasn't problems with the express, until the moment when i had to install express-generate globally.

Comment: it means it's started, goto your browser and navigate to `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Tried that - This webpage is not available.

Comment: goto your `./bin/www` file & see on which port it is listening. Navigate to that.

Comment: `node app.js` will do nothing, since the bootstrapping is done in `./bin/www`.

Comment: It is 3000. Sorry, maybe I did not explained it clearly. After I run the npm start command, it is not listening and seems to die (as if I stopped the server with ctrl+c)

Comment: any errors you are getting.

Comment: There are no errors...